# Shifting syntax error

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, optimization, arduino

I have a byte array:

```
byte data[2]
```

I want to to keep the 7 less significant bits from the first and the 3 most significant bits from the second.
I do this:

```
unsigned int the=((data[0]<<8 | data[1])<<1)>>6;
```

Can you give me a hint why this does not work?
If I do it in different lines it works fine.

Comment: @chris No, integer promotions. It's UB if `byte` is signed and `data[0] < 0`.

Comment: @DanielFischer, Good point, I forgot about that. Tricky language is tricky :p

Comment: so it is the casting i suppose that i miss?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @rahulmaindargi No, two open, two closed.

Comment: data[0]<<7 | ((unsigned int)data[1])>>5

Comment: How do you do it in two lines so that it works?  Maybe we can then see the mis-transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Can you give me a hint why this does not work?

Hint:

You have two bytes and want to preserve 7 less significant bits from the first and the 3 most significant bits from the second:

```
data[0]: -xxxxxxx    data[1]: xxx-----
```

-'s represent bits to remove, x's represent bits to preserve.

After this

```
(data[0]<<8 | data[1])<<1
```

you have:

```
the: 00000000 0000000- xxxxxxxx xx-----0
```

Then you make `>>6` and result is:

```
the: 00000000 00000000 00000-xx xxxxxxxx
```

See, you did not remove high bit from data[0].

Answer (score 2):

> Keep the 7 less significant bits from the first and the 3 most significant bits from the second.

Assuming the 10 bits to be preserved should be the LSB of the `unsigned int` value, and should be contiguous, and that the 3 bits should be the LSB of the result, this should do the job:

```
unsigned int value = ((data[0] & 0x7F) << 3) | ((data[1] & 0xE0) >> 5);
```

You might not need all the masking operands; it depends in part on the definition of `byte` (probably `unsigned char`, or perhaps plain `char` on a machine where `char` is unsigned), but what's written should work anywhere (16-bit, 32-bit or 64-bit `int`; signed or unsigned 8-bit (or 16-bit, or 32-bit, or 64-bit) values for `byte`).

Your code does not remove the high bit from `data[0]` at any point — unless, perhaps, you're on a platform where `unsigned int` is a 16-bit value, but if that's the case, it is unusual enough these days to warrant a comment.